# Clone Access database data to in-memory database like H2?

Tags: java, ms-access, h2

We have a diversity of data in a single Access .mdb file. This is an established process and cannot be changed: there are several Excel sheets with VBA-macros writing to this .mdb.

Every time we start our integration tests this file is accessed, which leads to concurrentModificationExceptions - because of the fact that it is on an internal shared public device.

Of course we could copy the file to a local folder and run the tests - but because I want to do it "the optimal way" I'd prefer to clone the data in a memoryDB (like H2) everytime intergration tests are started.

I ran into several problems copying the tables "one by one" via UCanAccess because there were a lot of datatype issues. Now the question:
Is there a possibility in Java to clone all of the Access data to an in-memory-db (like H2) without taking care of data types, like mappings from access-type to ... jdbc-data-types... right?

Comment: *"Is there a possibility in Java to clone all of the Access data to an in-memory-db"* - That is exactly what the UCanAccess driver does when you open a database using the default `memory=true` mode. It copies the data from the tables in the Access database file into in-memory HSQLDB tables. Have you tried running your tests just using the UCanAccess `Connection`?

Comment: Well... we did... but there are still several concModExceptions. Obviously the implementation seems to be the problem... I never worked with UCanAccess and supposed it is just a connection framework to ms-access. Well, I'll have a look and will report the results.

Comment: Were the "concurrentModificationExceptions" happening when you were trying to copy the production database to a local folder?

Comment: @GordThompson: no, it was during the test runtime. But nevertheless I have to thank you, you were totaly right with your "memory=true" suggest. I redesigned our integration tests Structure and loaded the DB with this flag -> everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Gord Thompson we switched the connection to our MS-Access-DB from

```
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFile.getCanonicalPath() + ";", username, pass);
```

to

```
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFile.getCanonicalPath() + ";memory=true", username, pass);
```

and this was the wanted result. UCanAccess did the job, so there is no need to solve the mentioned data type issues with H2.